# How to update coffee script?

Tags: npm

I got a following error when I tried to watch coffee scripts by `coffee -o js -cw coffee`.

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/command.js:321
        throw e;
              ^
Error: watch Unknown system errno 28
    at errnoException (fs.js:636:11)
    at FSWatcher.start (fs.js:663:11)
    at Object.watch (fs.js:691:11)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/command.js:287:27
    at Object.oncomplete (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/command.js:100:11)
```

I have no idea what is going with error.

Then I checked the versions, `coffee -v` is 1.6.1 and `node -v` is v0.6.12.

According the official site( http://coffeescript.org/ ) the latest version is 1.6.3, so I wanted update `coffee` by `npm update -g coffee-script`, but this fails also.

```
npm WARN coffee-script@1.6.1 package.json: bugs['name'] should probably be bugs['url']
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script
```

How can I update coffee script?

*Edit 2013/10/11*

In my coffee script directory there is only one file `box_wrapper.coffee`.

```
$ ->
  $("body").children().wrap ->
    "<div id='#{$(@).attr "id"}_box' class='wrapper'/>"
```

*Edit 2013/10/16*

I tried to re-install `coffee`, so I've done like this.

```
$ sudo npm -g rm coffee
npm WARN Not installed in /usr/local/lib/node_modules coffee
$ coffee -v
CoffeeScript version 1.6.1
```

I can't remove `coffee`. And I tried also like this.

```
$ sudo apt-get remove npm
$ npm -v
-bash: /usr/bin/npm: No such file or directory
$ sudo apt-get install npm
$ npm -v
1.1.4
$ sudo npm -g install coffee

# I omit a lot of `GET` parts.

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp/0.3.4
npm ERR! error installing express@3.2.6
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/assertion-error/1.0.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/growl
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/jade/0.26.3
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/diff/1.0.2
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp/0.3.5
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/glob/3.2.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ms/0.3.0
npm ERR! error rolling back express@3.2.6 Error: UNKNOWN, unknown error '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee/node_modules/express'
npm ERR! error installing coffee@0.0.1

npm ERR! EEXIST, file already exists '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee/node_modules/mocha/node_modules'
npm ERR! File exists: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee/node_modules/mocha/node_modules
npm ERR! Move it away, and try again.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Linux 3.2.0-54-generic-pae
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "-g" "install" "coffee"
npm ERR! cwd /home/ironsand
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.12
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.4
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee/node_modules/mocha/node_modules
npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee/node_modules/mocha/node_modules/___debug.npm
npm ERR! fstream_type Directory
npm ERR! fstream_class DirWriter
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! message EEXIST, file already exists '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee/node_modules/mocha/node_modules'
npm ERR! errno {}
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/nodejs/fstream/lib/writer.js:161:23
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (/usr/lib/nodejs/mkdirp.js:34:53)

npm ERR! EEXIST, file already exists '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee/node_modules/mocha/node_modules'
npm ERR! File exists: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee/node_modules/mocha/node_modules
npm ERR! Move it away, and try again.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Linux 3.2.0-54-generic-pae
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "-g" "install" "coffee"
npm ERR! cwd /home/ironsand
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.12
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.4
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee/node_modules/mocha/node_modules
npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee/node_modules/mocha/node_modules/___debug.npm
npm ERR! fstream_type Directory
npm ERR! fstream_class DirWriter
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! message EEXIST, file already exists '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee/node_modules/mocha/node_modules'
npm ERR! errno {}
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/nodejs/fstream/lib/writer.js:161:23
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (/usr/lib/nodejs/mkdirp.js:34:53)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ironsand/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

And `npm-debug.log` is a blank file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error occurs because of old `nodejs` version.
Ubuntu 12.04, 13.04 default `nodejs` package is version `0.6.x`.

I updated `nodejs` version to `v0.10.20` like this, then the problem is solved.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties python g++ make
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

I followed the instruction from here. 
https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager

Comment: Ohh... so it was a bug

Comment: Many thanks this also fix my problem with bower installation

Answer (score 5):

The thing is that the npmjs repositories doesn't have the 1.6.3 but the 1.6.1. I will presume here, but the reason of your error is with *your* code, not CoffeeScript:

```
    } catch (e) {
      if (e.code !== 'ENOENT') {
        throw e;
      }
    }
  };
```

The above indicates that if `e.code` isn't exactly the same as `ENOENT` then throw the error, which in your case is:

```
Error: watch Unknown system errno 28
    at errnoException (fs.js:636:11)
    at FSWatcher.start (fs.js:663:11)
    at Object.watch (fs.js:691:11)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/command.js:287:27
    at Object.oncomplete (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/command.js:100:11)
```

I would check the file `fs.js` and/or reverting the last changes you did to your code. CoffeScript is doing just fine, the problem is elsewhere.

---

### For people that might actually update their CoffeScript

If you really want to use the latest CoffeScript, then the method to install it is using:

```
npm install -g http://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/tarball/master
```

This will install the latest CoffeScript, if you want the 1.6.3 version then you should use:

```
npm install -g http://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/tarball/1.6.3
```

Replace the `1.6.3` with the version of CoffeScript you like.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer! But I never touched `fs.js`, and I don't even know where is it. I searched the file by `locate "fs.js"`, but it appears only `*-refs.js` or `*-defs.js`, there is no "fs.js" file. What should I next to solve this problem?

Comment: Just to make certain, I added information about my coffee script.

Comment: As far as I know, I've not touched any coffee script files. I installed coffee and am using default setting. I've never even try to change settings. I'm create a folder `~/Dropbox/www/mysite` and `cd` to the direcotory and a `index.html` file, and create `js` and `coffee` directries. After that copy some `.js` files to `js` directory that I use and create `box_wrapper.coffee` in `coffee` directory.

Comment: And do `coffee -o js -cw coffee`, then I got the error.

Comment: I've done same thing again in my home directory. But error message is same.

Comment: I noticed `coffee -v` show version of coffee, but `coffee` shows error message `node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick` and more.

Comment: I tried to remove npm and coffeescript completely, but I couldn't find the way to do it. I added info into my question.